# Why does jQuery not update the input value with $("form :input[name="some_input"]).val();

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a dual login script that logs a user into two separate systems (form a & form b) from another separate login (dual).

```
<h2>Dual Login</h2>
    <form id="dual">
    username<br>
    <input type="input" name="un" value="1234567"><br>
    password<br><input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<h2>Login A</h2>
<form id="login_a" action="#" method="post">
    username<br>
    <input id="un_a" type="input" name="un_a" value="hi"><br>
    password<br>
    <input id="pw_a" type="password" name="pw_a"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<h2>Login B</h2>
<form id="login_b" method="post" action="#">
    username 1<br>
    <input id="un_b" type="text" name="un_b" value=""><br>
    password<br>
    <input id="pw_b" type="password" name="pw_b"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('#dual :input[name="un"]').blur(function(){
    un = $('#dual :input[name="un"]').val();
    $('#un_a').val(un);
    $('#un_b').val(un);
});
```

Here is a fiddle that illustrates the working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mckinselberg/bPapQ/

My question is: Why is it that when I try to update the values this way, it doesn't work:

```
$('#dual :input[name="un"]').blur(function(){
    un = $('#dual :input[name="un"]').val();
    $('#form_a :input[name="un_a"]').val(un);
    $('#form_b :input[name="un_b"]').val(un);
});
```

Here is a fiddle that illustrates the non-working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mckinselberg/BbKTG/

Comment: Your fiddle contains no such element, `#form_a`, or `#form_b`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#form_a             // supposed to be  $('#login_a
$('#form_b             // supposed to be  $('#login_b
```

**Check your id's**

```
<form id="login_a" 
<form id="login_b"
```

It's a simple explanation. You are selecting the wrong `id's`

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/BbKTG/5/)**

Comment: Thanks! I thought I'd checked it thoroughly. (sound of head slamming against desk)

Answer (score 1):

You were selecting `#form_a` and `#form_b`, when the ID used on the forms in your HTML is `#login_a` and `#login_b` respectively. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BbKTG/3/

Answer (score 1):

Your ID's don't match... you have `login_a` in the HTML and `form_a` in the jQuery